# Redirects using http instead of https when in k8s with tls hand off by ingress

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a service running in a docker container in Kubernetes. It has https/tls hand off by an ingress and then into the container via http. My issue is when the webApp that's running in the container returns a redirect or a request for the resource, it is returning http endpoints not https.

So for example:

Request: https://my.service

Returns redirect: http://my.service/login.html

Is there any way around this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like you a http-only service :-). Can you provide your service manifest. Check your redirect URL. You might have a configuration errors.

Comment: Some applications solve this through providing a "redirect"-url including the http(s)-scheme used as configuration.

Comment: what ingress controller are you using?

Comment: Is the app redirecting from http to https? If yes, then you'll have to disable it.

Comment: @HelloWorld I am using the nginx-ingress-1.11.3 controller. This is behind a bunch of firewalls that only have port 443 available, so I can't just add the http ingress unfortunately.=

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing I don't believe that it is a http only service. I know for instance, that I could enable https on the service but that's not really what I am after.

Comment: @Alex the application in question is Splunk.

Comment: @DávidMolnár the app is redirecting to http, because it believes that's how it is being consumed, due to the fact the ingress does that tls hand off.

Comment: Yeah, then that behavior needs to be disabled in the app itself. Maybe via a configuration or something...

Comment: @DávidMolnár The answer is in the nginx-ingress controller form below. It now works a treat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see your application is returning redirects to `http` and you are trying to rewrite these `http` to `https` in responses.

When using [kubernetes nginx ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) adding these two annotations to your ingress object will solve your problem:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-from: http
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-to: https
```

More details can be found in [ingress controller annotation descriptions](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#proxy-redirect) and in [official nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect)

Let me know it it helped.

Comment: You sir are amazing! This works perfectly thank you. I can't up vote because I need more points.

Comment: Awesome sorry, still a bit new to all this!