# webserver in kubernetes incoming https allowed reply content in http blocked

Tags: http, kubernetes, https

I deployed a web server in angular material in k8s and configured an ingress for this service, the ingress allows https incoming queries. The  This webserver talks to a backend service via http to get and content of the query.

-------https------->ingress---->webserver--------http-------->service to answer query

I've got an error that the ingress blocks reply content as it's from http

The error message is:
Mixed Content:

```
The page at https://myserver.com was loaded over ####.js HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest  endpoint: "http://backend:port/end_point"
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over https
```

I tried the below solution but it did not work for me.
[Redirects using http instead of https when in k8s with tls hand off by ingress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59258254/redirects-using-http-instead-of-https-when-in-k8s-with-tls-hand-off-by-ingress)

How can I fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Could you help us by showing us [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can assist you with your problem

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature of the browser object (your web server) which prevent HTTP content loaded via a secure page (HTTPS). You need to upgrade your backend to support HTTPS.